# LocalStorage items disappear after refreshing website

Tags: javascript

***JavaScript:***

I have created a todo app in which I am rendering "li" from localStorage but when I refresh it disappears from the website.

```
add todo to DOM function which adds li to the DOM
function addToDoToDom(todo) {
  const li = document.createElement("li");

  li.innerHTML = `
    <input
    type="checkbox"
    id="${todo.id}" ${todo.completed ? "checked" : ""}
    class="custom-checkbox"
  />
  <label for="${todo.id}">${todo.text}</label>
  
  <div>
  <img src="images/delete.svg" class="delete" data-id="${todo.id}" />
  </div>
  `;

  updateLocalStorage();
  todoList.append(li);
}
```

Comment: we can't see the code that deals with localStorage - i.e. what does `updateLocalStorage` do? where do you READ from localStorage on page load? etc

Answer (score 1):

It could have happened for 2 reasons, it could be that you are using localStorage.clear() somewhere in the code, or the updateLocalStorage() function is resetting with the todo value as undefined on the last call. Try putting a conditional before doing the update to the localSotrage, inside the function for the todo value. updateLocalStorage(), if you can show the content of this function it would help to understand what is happening.

Comment: update function is only responsible for setting the todo items in localStorage and I have not added LocalStorage.clear() anywhere in my code.

Comment: function updateLocalStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(toDoItems));
}

Comment: I think when the page refreshes the updateLocalStorage() function
is resetting the value to undefined.

Comment: localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(toDoItems ?? {id:'1', text:'Default'})); try this and see what appears in local storage